# Error: The specified registry key does not exist. Trying to connect to TFS 2012 using network credentials.

Tags: azure, tfs, azure-web-app-service, azure-devops

```
var tfsUri = new Uri(credentials.ProjectCollectionUrl);
var user = new NetworkCredential(credentials.Username, credentials.Password);
var tfs = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(tfsUri, user);
tfs.EnsureAuthenticated();
```

The webapp is deployed on azure. It works locally but breaks on the server.

StackTrace:
*   at Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey.Win32Error(Int32 errorCode, String str)
   at Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey.CreateSubKeyInternal(String subkey, RegistryKeyPermissionCheck permissionCheck, Object registrySecurityObj, RegistryOptions registryOptions)
   at Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey.CreateSubKey(String subkey, RegistryKeyPermissionCheck permissionCheck, RegistryOptions options)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Common.TokenStorage.RegistryTokenStorageHelper.GetRootKey(String subkeyName)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Common.TokenStorage.RegistryTokenStorage.RetrieveToken(VssTokenKey tokenKey)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Common.TokenStorage.VssTokenStorage.Retrieve(VssTokenKey tokenKey)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.TfsClientCredentialStorage.RetrieveToken(Uri serverUrl, VssCredentialsType credentialType)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.CookieCredential.OnCreateTokenProvider(Uri serverUrl, HttpWebResponse response)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.IssuedTokenCredential.CreateTokenProvider(Uri serverUrl, HttpWebResponse response, IssuedToken failedToken)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.TfsClientCredentials.TryGetTokenProvider(Uri serverUrl, IssuedTokenProvider& provider)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.Channels.TfsHttpRequestHelpers.PrepareWebRequest(HttpWebRequest webRequest, Guid sessionId, String operationName, CultureInfo cultureInfo, TfsRequestSettings settings, TfsClientCredentials credentials, IdentityDescriptor impersonate, IssuedToken& currentToken, IssuedTokenProvider& tokenProvider)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.Channels.TfsHttpRequestHelpers.CreateSoapRequest(Uri requestUri, Guid sessionId, String soapAction, String operationName, CultureInfo cultureInfo, TfsRequestSettings settings, TfsClientCredentials credentials, IdentityDescriptor impersonate, IssuedToken& currentToken, IssuedTokenProvider& tokenProvider)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.Channels.TfsHttpWebRequest.CreateWebRequest()
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.Channels.TfsHttpWebRequest.SendRequest()
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.Channels.TfsHttpRequestChannel.Request(TfsMessage message, TimeSpan timeout)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.Channels.TfsHttpClientBase.Invoke(TfsClientOperation operation, Object[] parameters, TimeSpan timeout, Object[]& outputs)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Client.Registration.GetRegistrationEntries(String toolId)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Client.RegistrationProxy.GetRegistrationEntries(String toolId)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Client.RegistrationService.RefreshMemoryCache()
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Client.RegistrationService.RefreshCachesIfNeeded(Boolean direct)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Client.RegistrationService.GetRegistrationEntries(String toolId)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Client.PreFrameworkServerDataProvider.FindServiceLocation(String serviceType, String toolId)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Client.PreFrameworkServerDataProvider.LocationForCurrentConnection(String serviceType, Guid serviceIdentifier)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.TfsConnection.EnsureProviderConnected()
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.TfsConnection.EnsureAuthenticated()

We're not sure what causes it to break.

Answer (score 4):

You can't use the old API for TFS on Azure as you need to have Team Explorer installed on the server.

However, if you use the new Nuget packages for the TFS API (Supports new Rest API on TFS 2015, and old client API for 2012, 2013, and 2015)...

http://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.ExtendedClient/

This will let you connect to TFS from Azure without Team Explorer...

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use TFS Api on Azure Webapp as it requires Team Explorer installed. Refer to this link from MSDN for details: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb130146.aspx